# Prove $\frac{1+n^3sin(n)}{n^3}a_n$ converges, where $a_n$ is a sequence which converges to 0.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Prove $\frac{1+n^3sin(n)}{n^3}a_n$ converges, where $a_n$ is a sequence which converges to 0.

I'm not sure what the best way to prove this is. I've attempted below, but the question is only worth few marks in the practice test it's from, so I'm wondering if there is a better / quicker / simpler way to prove this.

(omitted some of the finer details for brevity's sake)

**Firstly notice**:

$\frac{1+n^3\sin(n)}{n^3}a_n = \frac{1}{n^3}a_n + \sin(n)a_n$

**Take** $\frac{1}{n^3}a_n$:

Both $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and $a_n$ converge to 0
$\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^3}a_n$ converges to 0 (sum of 2 convergent sequences converge to sum of limits).

**Take** $\sin(n)a_n$:

$-a_n \leq \sin(n)a_n \leq a_n$
$\Longrightarrow \sin(n)a_n$ converges to 0 (By squeeze theorem).

**Finally**, it follows that:

$\frac{1+n^3\sin(n)}{n^3}a_n = \frac{1}{n^3}a_n + \sin(n)a_n$ converges to 0 (Again, sum of 2 convergent sequences converge to sum of limits).

Comment: For the first term you said " Both $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and $a_n$ converge to 0
$\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^3}a_n$ converges to 0 (sum of 2 convergent sequences converge to sum of limits)". You were supposed to say "Both $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and $a_n$ converge to 0
$\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^3}a_n$ converges to 0 (**product** of 2 convergent sequences converge to **product** of limits)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also argue that $\frac{1 + n^3\sin(n)}{n^3} \leq \frac{1+n^3}{n^3} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ so multiplying by $a_n$ shows that the limit tends to $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: I like this approach much better, and was probably how the question was intended to be solved. Thank you.